# How to Reflash Toshiba Satellite L855-10P BIOS in a Linux Distro?

Tags: linux, bios, toshiba, flashrom

Hi I need to Reflash the BIOS of my Toshiba Satellite L855-10P using a Linux distro.

How can one do this?

I have found lots of info on how to read the BIOS (windows & Linux), dump memory from it (Linux), and installation via windows & / usb / floppy but not reflashing in Linux.

Comment: Many of those notebooks have proprietary programs and do not have a Linux version.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use Toshiba's utility on [THIS PAGE](http://support.toshiba.com/support/viewContentDetail?contentId=4001551) ??

Comment: Is it UEFI based? If you flash it, does it reboot into an UEFI environment from where the flashing is done?

Comment: @phk - how can I tell if the BIOS is UEFI based? When you ask me about flashing it, are you talking about via specific OS or another method?

Comment: @melburslan I wasn't aware of that. I'll have a look at it.

Comment: @unseen_rider On some notebooks (e.g. newer HP ones) the flashing can be done through a special OS on a separate partition which is also used for hardware tests and such (called "UEFI Support Environment"). You basically just unpack the BIOS setup file for Windows and copy the image into this location and then boot into this OS and this way you can flash your BIOS without using Windows.

Comment: @phk - ok I can't do this currently since my laptop didn't come with factory restore disk when purchased - I think I may need to get one. Also due to many reinstallations the original OEM parturition is no longer there.

Comment: @phk where is the BIOS setup file for Windows located?